# WCF - exception in client when data returned gets large

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF server.  One of the calls that a client can make generates an array of data as its response.  Each data item is approximately 6k, and it seems that when the array gets large enough (about 650 items or so), the WCF client gives the following exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the
>   HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:8080/TCA/TCAService. 
>   This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol.  This could also be due to
>   an HTTP request context being aborted
>   by the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down).  See server
>   logs for more details.

The server is not shut down, and responds with valid data if I change the function call to return a little less data.  I'm not sure how to get server logs, but this seems to be a client-side exception, so I have my doubts that server logs will help me at all.

I have played with MaxReceivedMessageSize on the client, but it doesn't help (it's currently at 16MB).  Any ideas? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'd also check the

```
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384"
maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

section in the binding. Those can make a difference as well.
It's mostly likely the `maxArrayLength`, as the default is ~16KB and you're getting about 3900KB back with 650 items at 6KB each.

Comment: I'm not using a config file, I'm setting these things programmatically and I do have binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;  which sets the items you suggested to obscenely high values.

Comment: Do you have those values set on both the server and client?

Comment: If the above doesn't help, try checking the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="" /> value. The default is 4MB, and you're hovering right around that level. See http://weblogs.asp.net/skoganti/archive/2004/02/22/78124.aspx

Comment: Yes, both server and client.  I'll try the maxRequestLength.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with package size, but in my case, the package size was bigger than yours (and the error message was "*Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is ’65536′*") . I resolved my problem configuring the binding for my service. I am posting below the entire binding (notice the readerQuotas):

```
<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IServiceRequest" 
            closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" 
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
            sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            transactionFlow="false" 
            transferMode="Buffered" 
            transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
            listenBacklog="10"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
            maxConnections="10"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas 
                maxDepth="32" 
                maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport 
                    clientCredentialType="Windows"
                    protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
        </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

I hope it works for you as well.

Here is the posting from my blog: [Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is ’65536′](http://blog.robertolopes.com/2011/01/17/maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an-object-graph-is-65536/)

Thanks,
Roberto